# Data Studio obtain a transposed table from BigQuery and hidden conditional formatting in text/strings

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

Several shops should be monitored about their status in a Data Studio dashboard.

There are less than 20 shops and I show here only two in the example. In the BigQuery table there is `shop` column and following columns: `status`, `info`, `sold_today` and `update_time`. The `shop` and `update_time` columns are always filled, but the other ones are filled only if there is a change.

**Task**: For each shop the last entries of all columns should be shown.

Here is the BigQuery code for the sample table:

```sql
create or replace table dsadds.eu.dummy as(
Select "shop A" as shop,  1000 as sold_today, "sale ABC" as info, 0 as status,timestamp( "2022-09-05") as update_time
union all select "shop A",null,null,1,"2022-09-06"
union all select "shop A" as shop,  500 as sold_today, "open" as status,3,"2022-09-01"
union all Select "shop B" as shop,  700 as sold_today, "open" as status,3,current_timestamp() as update_time
)
```

This table looks in Data Studio with conditional formatting, `Status=1` marked red, like this:
[image: raw data in Data Studio]

As you can see the "Shop A" is shown several times and with `null` values.
With following custom BigQuery in Data Studio I can obtain the last entry of each shop:

```sql
with tbl as 
(select shop,
array_agg(sold_today ignore nulls order by update_time desc limit 1)[safe_offset(0)] sold_today,
array_agg(info ignore nulls order by update_time desc limit 1)[safe_offset(0)] info,
array_agg(status ignore nulls order by update_time desc limit 1)[safe_offset(0)] status,

from dsadds.eu.dummy
group by 1
)
select * from tbl
```

resulting in following table, showing all needed information:

[image: right table in Data Studio]

**However, the users would like to have this table to be transposed** and look like this:

[image] -->
[image]

On the right hand side it is shown with the final textbox for the labeling of the rows.

Of course, it is possible to build for each entry a Scorecard, but with 10 shops and three field for each, the limit of charts per page was reached.

### Question

Is there a way to transpose a table and also do the conditional formatting?

Answer (score 2):

The task is to return one column for each shop and a column `id` to sort the results. A column has to have one data type and for different rows, we cannot return one time a string and the other time a integer. Thus all integer values have to be formatted in BigQuery as strings.

For transpose, we build an `tlb_array`. The grouping by the `shop` generates an array for each one. The array has as first entry the shop name `shop` and as 2nd entry the column `info` and as 3rd entry we cast the `sold_today` column, which is an integer value to a string. We also include an `id` as entry number. By `unnesting` this array we unflatten the data and group it again by `id` in the next `select` statement. Here, we create a column for each shop and the `if` condition only considers data for this shop. Thus we end up with a table with three rows, with the row number in `id`. The needed data is in the shop columns.

```sql
with tbl as 
(select shop,
array_agg(sold_today ignore nulls order by update_time desc limit 1)[safe_offset(0)] sold_today,
array_agg(info ignore nulls order by update_time desc limit 1)[safe_offset(0)] info,
array_agg(status ignore nulls order by update_time desc limit 1)[safe_offset(0)] status,

from dsadds.eu.dummy
group by 1
),
tlb_array as (
Select shop,X.* from tbl, 
  unnest([
    struct(1 as id,shop as value),
    struct(2,info),
    struct(3,cast(sold_today as string))]) X
)
select id,
any_value(if(shop="shop A",value,null)) as ShopA,
any_value(if(shop="shop B",value,null)) as ShopB,

 from tlb_array
 group by 1
```

Thus we return only text via strings. But we want to apply conditional formatting without adding further columns. The trick is to include special characters in the returned string.  `´` or `'` is possible, but this would disturb the user. Therefore, the use of space characters is a good way. There are several unicode characters for different space distances. Thus a number can be encoded to space characters. Following UDF has to be hosted by you. It encodes each decimal digit of a number in a different unicode space character.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `dsadds.us.number_to_space`(x INT64) AS (
(
    SELECT
      CONCAT(" ", 
        string_agg(SUBSTRING(
          CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING([0x2007, 0x2002, 0x2004, 0x2005, 0x2006, 0x2008, 0x2009, 0x200A, 0x202F, 0x205F]),
          y-47,1),"")
        ,"- ")
    FROM
      UNNEST(TO_CODE_POINTS(CAST(x AS string))) y )
);
```

Then you can use this function in your Custom BigQuery in Data Studio:

```sql
 
with tbl as 
(select shop,
array_agg(sold_today ignore nulls order by update_time desc limit 1)[safe_offset(0)] sold_today,
array_agg(info ignore nulls order by update_time desc limit 1)[safe_offset(0)] info,
array_agg(status ignore nulls order by update_time desc limit 1)[safe_offset(0)] status,

from dsadds.us.dummy
group by 1
),
tlb_array as (
Select shop,X.* from tbl, 
  unnest([
    struct(1 as id,concat(shop,dsadds.us.number_to_space(status)) as value),
    struct(2,concat(info,dsadds.us.number_to_space(status))),
    struct(3,cast(sold_today as string))]) X
)
select id,
any_value(if(shop="shop A",value,null)) as ShopA,
any_value(if(shop="shop B",value,null)) as ShopB,

 from tlb_array
 group by 1
```

This will result in following needed table. The (hidden) space characters have to be copied from the table (only in view not in edit mode of Data Studio possible) and condition formatting rules added (text contrains: ).  Please also adding a textbox over the first column to hide it and enter the labels for each row.

[image: Final transposed table with hidden information for condital formatting]